# Writing File and Reading from File in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file

```
import random

class Student:
    #easy way or short way to printing student details
    def student_details(self):
        print("Student number :",self.student_number)
        print("-----------")
        print("First Name : ",self._firstname)
        print("-----------")
        print("Last Name : ",self._lastname)
        print("-----------")
        print("Date Of Birth : ",self._date_of_birth)
        print("-----------")
        print("Gender : ",self._sex )
        print("-----------")
        print("Country of birth : ",self._country)
    
    #constructor for the class and assign the variables(eg:firstname)
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country):
        self.student_number = random.randint(1,18330751)
        self._firstname = firstname
        self._lastname = lastname
        self._date_of_birth = date_of_birth
        self._sex = sex
        self._country = country    
        
    
    def get_firstname(self):
        return self._firstname
    
    def set_firstname(self,firstname):
        self._firstname = firstname
   
    def get_lastname(self):
        return self._lastname
    
    def set_lastname(self,lastname):
        self._lastname = lastname
    
    def get_date_of_birth(self):
        return self._date_of_birth
    
    def set_date_of_birth(self,date_of_birth):
        self._date_of_birth = date_of_birth
   
    def get_sex(self):
        return self._sex
    
    def set_sex(self,sex):
        self._sex = sex
   
    def get_country(self):
        return self._country

    
    def set_country(self,country):
        self._country = country
    #this method for converting object when writing to file and reading the file
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country}"

student = []


while True:
    print("1. Enter 1 and you are going Write the contents of the student array to a file")
    print("-----------")
    print("2.Read student data from a file and populate the student array.")
    print("-----------")
    print("3.Add a new student")
    print("-----------")
    print("4. Enter 4 and you are going to see all students information")
    print("-----------")
    print("5. Enter 5 and you are going to write born year to find students who born in this year")
    print("-----------")
    print("6. Enter 6 and you are going to modify a student record by typing student number because you can't change student number")
    print("-----------")
    print("7. Enter 7 and you are going to write student number to delete student")
    print("-----------")
    print("8. Enter 8 and exit the program")
    print("-----------")
    print("You can choose what to do")
    
    option = int(input("Please write your option: "))
    print("-----------")
    
    if option == 1:
        
     f = open("cmse318.txt","w")
     
     for data in student:
                f.write(data)

                print("-----------")
                print("Successfully write to a  file!!")
                print("-----------")
                break
       
     f.close()
    
    if option == 2:
        f = open("cmse318.txt","r")
        
        for ln in f:
            firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country = ln.split(",")
            s = Student(firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country)
            student.append(s)
            print(s)
           
        f.close()

    
    if option == 3:
         firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country = map(str,input("Please Enter student details like this(cemal,göymen,2000,male,cyprus) : ").split(","))
         s = Student(firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country)
         student.append(s)
         print("-----------")
         print('Student created successfully!!')
         print("-----------")
         print("-----------")
         
    
    if option == 4 :
        for st in student:
            st.student_details()
            print("-----------")
            print("For now these are the students")
            print("-----------")
            
    
    if option == 5:
        year1 = int(input("Enter year to show students who born in this year(eg:2000): "))
        for dob in student:
            if (int(dob.get_date_of_birth()) == year1):
                
                dob.student_details()
                print("-----------")
                print("All students who born in ", year1)
                print("-----------")
                
    
    if option == 6:
        snr = int(input("Enter a student number: "))
        for sn in student:
            if sn.student_number == snr:
                firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country = map(str,input("Please Enter student details like this(cemal,göymen,2000,male,cyprus) :").split(","))
                sn.set_firstname(firstname)
                sn.set_lastname(lastname)
                sn.set_date_of_birth(date_of_birth)
                sn.set_sex(sex)
                sn.set_country(country)
                print("-----------")
                print("Student modify success")
                print("-----------")
                
    
    if option == 7:
        snr = int(input("Enter the student number to be deleted : "))
        for sn in student:
            if sn.student_number == snr:
                temp = sn
        student.remove(temp)
        print("-----------")
        print("Student deleted successfully")
        print("-----------")
        
    if option == 8:
        break
```

I need help in option 1 and option 2 about reading and writing file. In the reading file it does not read all students from a file it reads just one student and ıf there is more than one student in the file it gives an error. In the writing to file part, the problem is I cannot write the student array to file it just write the last element from the student array but I need all elements from my student array.

Comment: First, please format your code.

Comment: In option 1 you have a break statement in the for loop.  Thus, it stops after writing the information for one student.

Comment: Good idea is to cut out unnecessary parts. Often you would find the problem yourself in the process. DarryIG is right, break is the problem for writing. The reading part should be explained better: how does input looks like, what is expected behavior and what is actual output.

Comment: When I remove break its again to do not write the student array it just takes last element from student array but I want whole student array to write into file. In read from file it should read whole file then put into student array but it just read one student from file or just one element

Comment: @cemalgoymen--are you still have issues with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code can be improved as follows.

```
import random
    
class Student:
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country,student_number = None):
        # reuse student number when we read from file (i.e. if specified)
        # set new one if we don't have one
        self.student_number = student_number or random.randint(1,18330751) # or causes use of rand value 
                                                                           # if student_number = None
        self._firstname = firstname
        self._lastname = lastname
        self._date_of_birth = date_of_birth
        self._sex = sex
        self._country = country    
        
    def student_details(self):
        return (f"Student number : {self.get_student_number()}\n"
                f"-----------  First Name : {self.get_firstname()}\n"
                f"-----------  Last Name : {self.get_lastname()}\n"
                f"-----------  Date Of Birth : {self.get_date_of_birth()}\n"
                f"-----------  Gender : {self.get_sex()}\n"
                f"-----------  Country of birth : {self.get_country()}")
        
    def get_firstname(self):
        return self._firstname
    
    def set_firstname(self,firstname):
        self._firstname = firstname
   
    def get_lastname(self):
        return self._lastname
    
    def set_lastname(self,lastname):
        self._lastname = lastname
    
    def get_date_of_birth(self):
        return self._date_of_birth
    
    def set_date_of_birth(self,date_of_birth):
        self._date_of_birth = date_of_birth
   
    def get_sex(self):
        return self._sex
    
    def set_sex(self,sex):
        self._sex = sex
   
    def get_country(self):
        return self._country

    def set_country(self,country):
        self._country = country
        
    def get_student_number(self):
        return self.student_number
    
    def __str__(self):
        ' For serializing attributes to string --useful for writing to file '
        return (f"{self.get_student_number()},"
                f"{self.get_firstname()},"
                f"{self.get_lastname()},"
                f"{self.get_date_of_birth()},"
                f"{self.get_sex()},"
                f"{self.get_country()}")

def get_student_info():
   ' Use helper function to ensure student entry has correct number of fields '
    while True:
        while True:
            entry = input('''Please Enter student details comma delimited like this (firstname,lastname,date of birth,gender,country)
                            Example Emal,Göymen,4/15/2000,Male,Cyprus : ''')
            fields = entry.split(',')
            if len(fields) == 5:
                # Correct number of fields
                return fields
            else:
                print(f'Entry {entry} incorrecst format')
                print('Shoulbe be five comma delimitede fields i.e. firstname,lastname,date of birth,gender,country')
                

students = []

while True:
    print('''
            1. Write the contents of the student array to a file
                -----------
            2. Read student data from a file and populate the student array.
                -----------
            3. Add a new student
                -----------
            4. Display all students information
                -----------
            5. Information for students born in a particular year
                -----------
            6. Modify student record (you need to know student number)
                -----------
            7. Delete a student (you need to know student number)
                -----------
            8. Exit program
                -----------
            Enter option''')
    
    option = int(input("Please write your option: "))
    print("-----------")
   
    if option == 1:
        with open("cmse318.txt", "w") as f:
            for st in students:
                f.write(str(st) + '\n')
            print("-----------\nSuccessfully wrote to a  file!!\n-----------")
       
    if option == 2:
        with open("cmse318.txt","r") as f:
            students = []  # Start new student array
            for ln in f:
                student_number,firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country = ln.rstrip().split(",") # rstrip remove '\n' at end of line
                student_number = int(student_number)
                s = Student(firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country,student_number)
                students.append(s)
                print(str(s))
           
    if option == 3:
        firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country = get_student_info()
        s = Student(firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country)
        students.append(s)
        print('''-----------
                Student created successfully!!
                -----------
                -----------''')
         
    if option == 4 :
        print('''-----------
                For now these are the students
                -----------
                -----------''')

        for st in students:
            print(st.student_details())
            
    if option == 5:
        birth_year = input("Enter year to show students who born in this year(eg:2000): ")
        
        print("-----------"
              f"All students who born in {birth_year}"
              "-----------")
        for st in students:
            if birth_year in st.get_date_of_birth():  # e.g. birth_year = 2000, date_of_birth = "May 5, 2000" we get a match
                print(st.student_details())
                
    if option == 6:
        snr = int(input("Enter a student number: "))
        for sn in students:
            if sn.student_number == snr:
                firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,sex,country = get_student_info()
                sn.set_firstname(firstname)
                sn.set_lastname(lastname)
                sn.set_date_of_birth(date_of_birth)
                sn.set_sex(sex)
                sn.set_country(country)
                print("-----------\nStudent modify success\n-----------")
                break
        else:
            print(f"Student number {snr} not found!!!")
                
    
    if option == 7:
        snr = int(input("Enter the student number to be deleted : "))
        # Normally bad practice to delete elements in list while iterating over it, 
        # but in this case we are only deleting a single element so okay
        for sn in students:
            if sn.student_number == snr:
                students.remove(sn)
                print(f"-----------\nStudent {snr} deleted successfully")
                break
        else:
            print("Student {snr} not found")
        
    if option == 8:
        print('Exiting')
        break
```

Comment: @cemalgoymen--let me know if you have any questions on the code.